# Best Way to take an image from input and send it to server JavaScript React App

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, postgresql, reactjs

I'm looking for a solution to take an image from an input, convert it and send it to the server.

I'm using React.js for front-end and Node.js + Postgresql for the back-end.

When I take an image that has a low size there is no problem to convert into base64 and store the base64 in the database. But with a high-resolution image, the database told me that the request is too large and I need to compress it.

So I need another way to store an image because I don't think that converts an image to base64 is efficient, and a way to compress it in case handling a high-resolution image.

Currently, I use this method, but as I explained before I don't think this method is efficient and with high-resolution image server told me that request is too long.

Front-End : 
 Component where I pick the image:

```
<InsertItemComponent
  name={"UPDATE IMAGE"}
  cName={"input-file"}
  req={false}
  tType={"file"}
  onChange={this.handleImage}
 accept={".jpg, .jpeg, .png"}
/>
```

The class InsertItemComponent is a simple inputField where the type is 
 'file'
 function handleImage:

```
handleImage = e => {

    e.preventDefault();
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let file = e.target.files[0];

    reader.onloadend = () => {
        this.setState({
            image: reader.result,
            imgchange: true
        });           
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(file); 

}
```

And then send it to server when a user Click the button for sending new 
 modifications

In my database image has text type and in my server, i simply update the current image.

Comment: i'd recommend storing the images on s3 and having the user upload them directly to s3: https://github.com/odysseyscience/react-s3-uploader or https://medium.com/@tewolfe2/5-steps-to-uploading-files-and-images-to-s3-in-react-using-express-superagent-multer-and-46a9e72244a2 or https://medium.com/@kevinwu/client-side-file-upload-to-s3-using-axios-c9363ec7b530

Answer (score 0):

You can send the image within a `multipart/form-data` request to your server.

Then your server gets image from the request and saves it to the Memory or DiskStorage depending on your needs. Check it out the `Multer` library.

> Multer is a Node.js middleware for handling multipart/form-data, which is
>   primarily used for uploading files.

https://github.com/expressjs/multer